# How works events in MVC?

Tags: php, events, model-view-controller

I have read somethings about Events, more specifically on MVC context, but I can not understand how it works. I would like know which the function of each participant (Subscriber, Listener, Handler).

Thank you ;)

Comment: EDA patterns usually have nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC's (Model-View-Controller) events are triggered by a certain condition. Now I see you've already listed a few objects that handle events.

**Subscriber** - an object that provides ways to group results. Think of subscribing to a magazine and the group of people who are also subscribed to the magazine.

**Listener** - an object that "listens" for certain calls made. Whether that be AJAX or a db connection or *events*.

**Handler** - an object that literally handles a process or variables from a common request.

Here is an image that helps illustrate the concept of the MVC pattern.

[image: MVC]